# JavaでString型のISO 8601文字列を整形したい｡

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data APIで得られる動画の再生時間はISO 8601形式に従って`PT#M#S`という`String`型のデータで返されます｡  そこで質問なのですが表示する上でJavaを使ってこの文字列を`hh:MM:ss`という形式に変換したいと考えています｡そこで何か簡単な方法はありますでしょうか｡

よろしくおねがいします｡

**追記:**

YouTube Data APIの[リソース表現](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?hl=ja#resource)です｡ 再生時間は`contentDetails`の`duration`という項目です｡

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます｡Java 8 に対応していなかったので､ Hiroshi Yamamoto様の方法を使わせて頂きました｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分でパースしてもいいぐらいに簡単なフォーマットではありますが、きちんとしたものがほしければ、 [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) に良いパーサ ( [ISOPeriodFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISOPeriodFormat.html) ) が含まれています。

*PT_M_S.java:*

```java
public class PT_M_S {

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        final PeriodFormatter parser = ISOPeriodFormat.standard();
        final PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
            .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
            .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendSeconds().toFormatter();

        final Period pt10m30s = parser.parsePeriod( "PT10M30S");
        final Period pt1m2s = parser.parsePeriod( "PT1M2S");
        final Period pt1h2m3s = parser.parsePeriod( "PT01H2M3S");

        System.out.println(pt10m30s + 
            " = " + pt10m30s.toStandardSeconds() + 
            " = " + pt10m30s.toStandardDuration().getMillis() +
            " = " + fmt.print( pt10m30s));

        System.out.println(pt1m2s + 
            " = " + pt1m2s.toStandardSeconds() + 
            " = " + pt1m2s.toStandardDuration().getMillis() +
            " = " + fmt.print( pt1m2s));

        System.out.println(pt1h2m3s + 
            " = " + pt1h2m3s.toStandardSeconds() + 
            " = " + pt1h2m3s.toStandardDuration().getMillis() +
            " = " + fmt.print( pt1h2m3s));
    }

}
```

*Output:*

```
PT10M30S = PT630S = 630000 = 00:10:30
PT1M2S = PT62S = 62000 = 00:01:02
PT1H2M3S = PT3723S = 3723000 = 01:02:03
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 なら、[Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/time/Duration.html)が使えそうです。

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
public class DurationTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String text = "PT5M30S";
    Duration d = Duration.parse(text);
    long seconds = d.get(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    long hours = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((seconds % 3600) / 60);
    int secs = (int) (seconds % 60);
    System.out.format("%s => %d:%d:%d", text, hours, minutes, secs);
  }
}
```